# Probability inequality for sum of two random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

Does anyone know if the following inequalities are right? If yes, what is the reference for them?

For random variable $x$ and $y$:
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}(x+y \ge x_0 + y_0) \le \mathbb{P}(\{x\ge x_0\} \text{or} \{y\ge y_0\}).
\end{equation}

Comment: The first set is contained in the second, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be clear that 
$$\mathbb{P}(\{x < x_0\} \text{ and } \{y < y_0\} ) \leq \mathbb{P}(\{x+y < x_0 + y_0 \})$$ holds. 
Using 
$$ \mathbb{P}(\{x \geq x_0\} \text{ or } \{y \geq y_0\} ) = 1- \mathbb{P}(\{x < x_0\} \text{ and } \{y < y_0\} )$$ 
and 
$$ \mathbb{P}(\{x+y \geq  x_0 + y_0 \}) = 1 - \mathbb{P}(\{x+y < x_0 + y_0 \})$$
yields your first statement. Repeating this should give the more general statement.

Comment: Thanks, actually I proved it just like this. I'm just curious if there is any reference I can cite directly. Or it's too easy to mention it?

Comment: I wouldn't think a source is necessary; you could always give a one-line argument such as Robert Israel provided.

Answer (score 3):

Note that if $x + y \ge x_0 + y_0$, then $x \ge x_0$ or $y \ge y_0$
(i.e. if $x < x_0$ and $y < y_0$ we'd have $x + y < x_0 + y_0$).

Similarly for a sum of $J$ variables.

Comment: Thanks :) Brilliant arguments!